# Need PHP mailbox with outbox queue and bounce handling

Tags: php, email-bounces

Want your suggestions for mail outbox in php.

Overview of My requirement:
I need email template manager, outbox queue process and bounce handling with spam filter as well. I want process where email goes to message queue and cron send it one by one and check message status also. I m using PHPMailer for sending my mails. 
If mail sent success then it delete message from DB, but if bounced then into bouncelist..so before sending next mail it check bounce list for email address. Other thing is all mail should be queued from my code not from UI.

I found one PHPList (Its a newsletter Management) which has campaign with template and bounce handling also.

Is there any other ready PHP mailbox available. Want some suggestion its worth to use already created  and modify it or make it my own.

Thanks to all in advance

Comment: If you know nothing about this (which seems to be the case), I would go with a 3rd party service such as MailChimp.com - and they have APIs.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know mail handling with bounces handling and cron for process one by one message and also about templates for email. But My question here is for is there ready mailbox that I can use. As to create from scratch would take more time.